# Python program can't update mysql db column

Tags: python, mysql

I have created a python program (with python3 and mysql.connector library) that updates the value of a column in a MySQL DB. When I run the command `SELECT * FROM table_name` in python seems to have changed the value, but when I run this command in MySql WorkBench it drops me the table with no changes applied.

Here is my code:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "IP adress",
    user = "user",
    passwd = "password"
    )

mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute("USE db_name;")
mycursor.execute('UPDATE table_name SET column = value WHERE condition;')
mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name;')
print(mycursor.fetchone())
```

As I have previously mentioned, when I run the command `SELECT * FROM table_name` in python it seems like the changes have been applied, but when I run it in MySql Workbench it seems like no changes have been applied. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Either you're not connected to the same database, or you're in implicit transaction mode and are not committing the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

try : before `print(mycursor.fetchone())`

```
db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks so much that solved my problem!!